# Is it true to say that any matrix in row echelon form, with columns as vectors, has linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true to say that any matrix in row echelon form, excluding the zero matrix, with columns as vectors, has linearly independent vectors (of the original matrix before performing elementary row operations)? I'm wondering if I can use this as a faster method of checking for linear independence between the vectors of a set.

Thanks! :)

Comment: No. The zero matrix is already in row echelon form ...

Comment: That's true but let's classify that as an exception. :)

Comment: Although a slight adjustment, instead of adding the disclaimer at the end just make the hypothesis 'any non zero matrix'. Not saying the hypothesis is then true, but a better way to pose the questions.

Comment: No: the matrix whose unique non-zero entry is $a_{11}=0$ is another counterexample. If you put a lot of zeroes in any matrix and you get a contraditcion.

Comment: @Crostul Can you please clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: If you add "non zero matrix" then the claim is painfully trivial: **any** nonzero matrix, whether in REF or whatever,  has *at least* one linearly independent row/column, when seen as vector in some $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm trying to use this as a method for quickly determining whether a set of vectors is linearly independent. Is it valid?

Comment: @ThePointer Of course, but then you may have wanted to  express: if we take several vectors in $\;\Bbb F^n\;$ , form a matrix with them as rows and then we reduce the matrix by rows with elementary operations, at the end **all** the rows that are left which are not all/zero represent linearly independent vectors. This much is true and it is one of the easiest, most used methods to heck whether some finite set of vectors is lin. ind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether all column vectors are linearly independent, then no,
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

is an example of a matrix in row-echelon form that has rank 2, which means it not all 3 column vectors can be linearly independent.

You can put any matrix in row echelon form, and then it is easier to determine the rank (number of linearly independent column vectors) of a matrix: The rank stays the same under Gaussian elimination, so a matrix has rank $n$ if and only if its row echelon form has rank $n$.

If you want to know whether a matrix has *at least one* linearly independent column vector, then any nonzero matrix has at least rank 1, as @DonAntonio said in the comments.

Comment: @ThePointer In fact it is...

Comment: Oops, sorry. Of course it is. I'm confusing myself now.

Comment: Haha, I was getting anxious for forgetting stuff. Linear algebra was a long time ago for me...

Comment: I'm confused now. @DonAntonio, you said above that this method works. Or am I misinterpreting what you're saying?

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the question. "has linearly independent vectors" can be interpreted as "having at least one linearly independent vector" or "has full rank". I went with the second one in this question. Going to edit in the other intrepretation.

Comment: Oh, I see now. @DWe1 I'm referring to a matrix A which originally has columns as vectors of a set. I want to know if that set is linearly independent. I then apply elementary row operations till I get the matrix into row echelon form. Call this matrix A'. If A' is successfully in row-echelon form, then the vectors of the set (columns of the original matrix) are linearly independent? This is what I'm asking.

Comment: @The Pointer no, in A' not all column vectors need to be linearly independent. In fact, you can put any matrix in REF. However, when in REF, it is easier to check whether a matrix has linearly independent column vectors. See my example, it is in REF, but column 1 and 2 are linearly dependent, in fact, they are the same. That is easy to check, because it is in REF.

Comment: @The Pointer: If you have a matrix with $k$ linearly independent vectors, then it's REF also has $k$ linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a row echelon form (REF) for checking linear independence of a set of vectors.

Let's call *dominant* a column in a matrix in REF if it contains a *pivot* (in reduced row echelon form it will be a leading $1$, the terminology varies).

It's easy to see that

> **Fact 1.** *The dominant columns in a REF matrix make a linearly independent set.*
>
> **Fact 2.** *A nondominant column in a REF matrix is a linear combination of the dominant columns.*

As a consequence, the dominant columns form a *maximal linearly independent set* among the columns of the REF matrix.

The other important fact is that if $U$ is a REF of the matrix $A$, there exists an invertible matrix $F$ such that $U=FA$. For ease of notation, let's write $a_i$ for the columns of $A$ and $u_i$ for the columns of $U$. With $\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\}$ I denote any set of indices in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, where $n$ is the number of columns of $A$ and $U$; $\alpha_i$ will be scalars.

> **Theorem.** $\alpha_1a_{i_1}+\alpha_2a_{i_2}+\dots+\alpha_ka_{i_k}=0$ *if and only if* $\alpha_1u_{i_1}+\alpha_2u_{i_2}+\dots+\alpha_ku_{i_k}=0$.

Just multiply by $F$ or $F^{-1}$, recalling that $u_i=Fa_i$.

> **Corollary 1.** *The set of columns $\{a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\dots,a_{i_k}\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $\{u_{i_1},u_{i_2},\dots,u_{i_k}\}$ is linearly independent.*
>
> **Corollary 2.** $a_i=\alpha_1a_{i_1}+\alpha_2a_{i_2}+\dots+\alpha_ka_{i_k}$ *if and only if* $u_i=\alpha_1u_{i_1}+\alpha_2u_{i_2}+\dots+\alpha_ku_{i_k}$.

Putting together facts 1 and 2 with the theorem and its corollaries, you can see that, given vectors $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, you can form the matrix $A$ having them as columns, compute a REF $U$ (the RREF, if you want) and easily decide whether the given vectors form a linearly independent set (if and only if every column in $U$ is dominant), but also easily extract a basis of the subspace spanned by the vectors: just take the vectors with indices corresponding to the dominant columns in $U$.